# How do I get the Formatted Value of a cell using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to use Google Apps Script to create a string by concatenating values from a selection of cells within a Google Spreadsheet. The problem is that I won't know whether the cells contain numbers, dates, or text. When the value is a number or date, I want to get the formatted value, the way it is displayed in the spreadsheet.

For example, here is a function that will return the value for a named range.

```
function getValueByName() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var theRange = ss.getRangeByName("theNamedRange");
    return theRange.getValue();
}
```

If the named range contains a date, formatted as 11/6/2013, then this function returns the value as "Wed Nov 06 2013 01:00:00 GMT-0700 (MST)".

I understand that what I am wanting would result in rounding errors for decimal values, but I don't care about that in this case. I just want to get the formatted value.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to know the type of data coming from each cell and handle it the right way in each case...

if it's a string, keep it as it is, if it's a date use `Utilities.formatDate` to show it the way you want ([see doc here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities?hl=fr-FR#formatDate%28Date,String,String%29)) and if it's a number you can also format it as necessary using `Utilities.formatString` ([see doc here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities?hl=fr-FR#formatString%28String,Object...%29)).

To get the type, use `instanceof`, for an example have a look [at this recent post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19738788/the-simplest-way-of-check-if-a-data-type-of-an-element-in-an-array-is-a-date-obj/19740223#19740223)

Comment: Am I to understand that there is no way to simply retrieve the text of a cell as displayed?? That seems awfully hard to believe.

Answer (score 3):

**I believe the existing answers are now outdated, as a new function [getDisplayValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range?hl=en#getDisplayValue()) seems to be what OP is looking for.**

---

Using your example, we can get the formatted value, in this case *30%*, of a range (cell) like this:

```
function getValueByName() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var theRange = ss.getRangeByName("A1Notation");
  var value = theRange.getValue() // 0.3
  var formattedValue = theRange.getDisplayValue(); // 30%
  return formattedValue;
}
```

This returns the displayed value of the top-left cell in the range, so useful if the range only has one value. Use [getDisplayValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range?hl=en#getDisplayValues()) for a larger range.

Answer (score 2):

There's a lib for that! [SheetConverter library](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/custom-methods/sheetconverter).

Gist [here](https://gist.github.com/mogsdad/6455765).

Here's how you could get a single formatted cell:

```
var formattedValue = SheetConverter.convertCell(value, format);
```

You'll find other goodies to convert whole ranges into HTML tables, or generate the HTML for a single cell (including fonts, background colors, text colors, and most other formatting elements).

Disclosure: I'm the library author. But that's not my picture on the "ScriptExamples" site!