# String types and text output formatting

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I wrote a Google Apps Script that pulls a single spreadsheet cell from new Google Form entries and sends its contents via email.

The script is working nicely, but the cell content is sent as a single block of text (newlines, paragraphs, etc are dropped). The Google Form entry is of "Paragraph/Long Text" type and I'd like to maintain the authors' formatting in the generated email.

I am tinkering with string types, but can't quite find the right combination. Any advice will be immensely appreciated. Code below.

```
function SendEmail() {

    // find out how many rows exist
    var numRows = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A:A").getLastRow();

    // fetch entry
    var messageRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Form Response").getRange("D" + numRows);

    // build message
    var message = {
        to: "destination@email.net",
        subject: "New Entry Posted",
        htmlBody: 'Hello, a new entry was posted.<p>&nbsp;<p>' + messageRange.getValues() + "<p>&nbsp;<p><a href=\"www.some_link.com\">Link here</a>."
    };

    // send
    MailApp.sendEmail(message);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Keeping Line-Breaks

For preserving line-breaks, the issue is text based line breaks (carriage return, `\r`, or newline, `\n`) are ignored in HTML. The best ways to create spacing between lines is to either use the dedicated ["line break" element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br), or separate text into individual elements and add spacing with CSS.

Luckily, converting Google Sheets line breaks into HTML is really easy. Simply change `messageRange.getValue()` to `messageRange.getValue().replace(/[\r\n]{1,2}/g,"<br>")`.

#### Advanced Formatting

If you are looking to preserver more advanced formatting, such as colors and images, the solution gets a bit trickier. Both `range.getValue()` and event `range.getRichTextValue().getText()` both return plain text. In order to convert to HTML, you need to use a bunch of other methods, like `range.getFontColors();`, and parse the output into CSS and combine it with the plain text value. There is a dedicated library called [SheetConverter](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/custom-methods/sheetconverter) to accomplish this, and you can see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26745765/11447682) for details.

#### Other things I noticed:

I noticed a few other things about your code you might want to change. You might have noticed in my solution that I used `messageRange.getValue()`, but in your code you have `messageRange.getValues()`. This is because you want a single value, but `range.getValues()` is for getting multiple values out of a range of > 1 cells.

You also have malformed HTML in your `htmlBody`. You open a bunch of `<p>` tags, but never close them with `</p>`.

Another thing is that the way you get the last row doesn't really make sense. You check the last row of "A:A" in the active sheet, but the active sheet can change and there is no guarantee that it is the same as "Form Response", or that A:A has the same last row as D:D. I think a safer solution would be something like this (which also includes the above recommended changes):

```
function SendEmail() {

    var formResponseSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Form Response");

    // fetch entry
    var messageRange = formResponseSheet.getRange("D" + formResponseSheet.getLastRow());

    // build message
    var message = {
        to: "destination@email.net",
        subject: "New Entry Posted",
        htmlBody: 'Hello, a new entry was posted.<p>' + messageRange.getValue().replace(/[\r\n]{1,2}/g,"<br>") + "</p><a href=\"www.some_link.com\">Link here</a>."
    };

    // send
    MailApp.sendEmail(message);

}
```

Comment: Joshua: it worked. Thank you for your help, I sincerely appreciate it!